# htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given php

Tags: php, arrays, string

so im trying to call this funktion in my tpl but i get the error massage:
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/virtual/www.eless.de/ivanovm/lib/data/Contract.class.php on line 342

Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/virtual/www.eless.de/ivanovm/templates/compiled/d9e0e5ca75d171cae06b57137aa1475b7f24e533_2.file.contractList.tpl.php on line 135
(line 135 is empty)

```
public function getYearlyConsumption()
    {
        $yearlyConsumption = [];
        $idx = 0;

        //company bestimmen und zugehörige consumption points aufrufen
        $company = System::getUser()->getCompany();
        $consumptionPoints = $company->getConsumptionPoints();

        foreach ($consumptionPoints as $consumptionPoint) {
            if ($consumptionPoint->status == 1) {
                $yearlyConsumption[$idx] += $consumptionPoint->getYearlyConsumptionInt();
                $idx++;

            }
        }
        return $yearlyConsumption;
    }
```

here is the call in my template (this mistake pops up for every funnction i'm trying to call the code above is just one example

```
{foreach from=$data item=item}
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="{System::getLink('contractView')}"><input type="button" style="text-align: center"
                                                                           width="200em"
                                                                           value="&raquo;{$item->contractID}&laquo;"></a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {$item->date|date_format:"%d.%m.%Y"}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {$item->selectedPrice}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {$item->getYearlyConsumption()}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {$item->getConsumptionPointsCount()}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {if $item->status == 0}
                            <span {literal}style="background-color:#ff9933"{/literal}>Wird Bearbeitet</span>
                        {/if}
                        {if $item->status == 1}
                            <span {literal}style="background-color:#33cc33"{/literal}>Abgeschlossen</span>
                        {/if}
                        {if $item->status == 2}
                            <span {literal}style="background-color:#ff0000"{/literal}>Stoniert</span>
                        {/if}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {/foreach}
```

Comment: `return $yearlyConsumption` will return an array. I don't understand what you expected the <undisclosed> templating engine to do with that.

Comment: i never used templates before so i tought i could call my function from my class with smarty.. isnt it possibille?

Comment: Yes it is possible but the function must return something that can be written on the page(e.g. a string, integer, float) you're returning an array so you need to flatten it somehow.

Comment: i wanted to show the yearly usage for every contract the customer has

Comment: do you have any tip for me? im realy stuck atm ._.

Comment: Could always do another loop `{foreach from=$item->getYearlyConsumption() item=c} <td>{$c}</td>`

Answer (score 0):

getYearlyConsumption() returns array and you trying to display array as string including it in {}.
{} tags call htmlspecialchars() function.

Comment: yea i got the problem in my code im just not sure how to solve it by now, guess i will try it with sections instead of foreach

Comment: Try this: 
{foreach from=$item->getYearlyConsumption() item=el}
{$el}
{/foreach}